# Svelte Material UI colored snackbar

Tags: sass, material-ui, svelte, sveltekit

In a SvelteKit app,
I'm trying to use a smui colored snackbar.

My src/theme/_smui-theme.scss is:

```
@use 'sass:color';
@use '@material/theme/color-palette';
@use '@material/theme/theme-color';
@use '@material/snackbar/mixins';

// Svelte Colors!
@use '@material/theme/index' as theme with (
  $primary: #ff3e00,
  $secondary: #676778,
  $surface: #fff,
  $background: #fff,
  $error: color-palette.$red-900
);
...    
.mdc-snackbar.demo-success {
  @include mixins.fill-color(color-palette.$green-500);
  @include mixins.label-ink-color(
    theme-color.accessible-ink-color(color-palette.$green-500)
  );
}
 
.mdc-snackbar.demo-warning {
  @include mixins.fill-color(color-palette.$orange-500);
  @include mixins.label-ink-color(
    theme-color.accessible-ink-color(color-palette.$orange-500)
  );
}
 
.mdc-snackbar.demo-error {
  @include mixins.fill-color(color-palette.$red-500);
  @include mixins.label-ink-color(
    theme-color.accessible-ink-color(color-palette.$red-500)
  );
}
```

but compiling with **npm run smui-theme-light** I got an error:

```
This module was already loaded, so it can't be configured using "with".
node_modules/@material/theme/_index.scss
@forward './theme-color' show
[...]
src/theme/_smui-theme.scss
@use '@material/theme/theme-color';
[..]
@use '@material/theme/index' as theme with (
  $primary: #ff3e00,
```

How I can add these scss customizations for reusable components that live outside /src/routes?

Comment: Could you post a link to a minimal runnable project?

Comment: Check some of the docs to ensure you have proper commands and setup https://www.npmjs.com/package/smui-theme Without more context it'll be hard to answer your question.

Comment: did you ever found a solution ?? Following the documentation, but impossible to style the snackbar easily. 

Comment: @Jessy to have the context, you simply create a smui [themed project](https://sveltematerialui.com/THEMING.md) and try to add a styled [Colored snackbars](https://sveltematerialui.com/demo/snackbar/)

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the issue by adding it to app.scss so

```
@use '@material/snackbar/index' as snackabar;
@use '@material/theme/index' as theme;

.mdc-snackbar.snackbar--success {
  @include snackabar.fill-color(color-palette.$green-900);
  @include snackabar.label-ink-color(theme.accessible-ink-color(color-palette.$green-900));
}

.mdc-snackbar.snackbar--warning {
  @include snackabar.fill-color(color-palette.$orange-900);
  @include snackabar.label-ink-color(theme.accessible-ink-color(color-palette.$orange-900));
}

.mdc-snackbar.snackbar--error {
  @include snackabar.fill-color(color-palette.$red-900);
  @include snackabar.label-ink-color(theme.accessible-ink-color(color-palette.$red-900));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message `This module was already loaded, so it can't be configured using "with".` tells you that the statement with the `with` keyword is having issues.

All you have is to place the `@use '@material/theme/index' as theme with` line ***before*** you import `@use '@material/snackbar/mixins';`. Like this:

```
// Svelte Colors!
@use '@material/theme/index' as theme with (
  $primary: #ff3e00,
  $secondary: #676778,
  $surface: #fff,
  $background: #fff,
  $error: color-palette.$red-900
);

@use '@material/snackbar/mixins';
```